# Android Endless Recyclerview

Tags: android

I've inserted endless recyclerview on my project, but when I call my list vehicle fragment, it calls the method `onLoadMore(int x)` twice and calls the second page. But my fragment keeps in the list only 10 items.

If it is called twice, but kept with all the data, have no problem, but it is loosing the data.

Can someone help me to solve this problem please?

**My Fragment**

```
    public class ListVehicleFragment extends BaseFragment implements ListVehicleContract.View, ItemVehicleClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_vehicle, container, false);

        setupListVehiclesRecyclerView();

        mPresenter = new ListVehiclePresenter(this, NextCarApplication.getInstance().getNetworkService());

        if (getArguments() != null) {

            vehicles = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("VEHICLE_SEARCH");

            mAdapter.addItem(vehicles);
        } else {
            showProgressDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.title_wait), getString(R.string.prompt_loading_wait));
            mPresenter.searchListVehicleByPage(page);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void setupListVehiclesRecyclerView() {
        rvListVehicles.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvListVehicles.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new ListVehicleAdapter(getActivity(), vehicles, this);
        rvListVehicles.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        rvListVehicles.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                if (getArguments() == null) {
                    if (!isLast) {
                        showProgressDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.title_wait), getString(R.string.prompt_loading_wait));
                        mPresenter.searchListVehicleByPage(current_page);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyListVehicleSuccess(PaginatedVehicle paginatedVehicle) {
        isLast = paginatedVehicle.isLast();

        mAdapter.addItem(paginatedVehicle.getContent());
        hideProgressDialog();
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
@Override
public void searchListVehicleByPage(Integer page) {
    mNetworkService.getAPI().getVehicles(page).enqueue(new RestCallback<GenericResponse<PaginatedVehicle>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(GenericResponse<PaginatedVehicle> response) {
            mListVehicleView.notifyListVehicleSuccess(response.getResult());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(ErrorResponse error) {
            mListVehicleView.notifyFailure();
        }
    });

}
```

**My EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener**

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    private int current_page = 0;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = mLinearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

Comment: Presenter code?

Comment: I'll edit my question...

Comment: And what do you do in ListVehicleAdapter.addItem ?

Comment: Use a text editor to see...

public void addItem(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehiclesArray) {
        if (vehicles != null) {
            vehicles.addAll(vehiclesArray);
        } else {
            vehicles = vehiclesArray;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: It all looks right. Are you sure that you are getting fresh data from api?

Comment: Yes, i put the break point, it's calling twice times, calling the current_page = 1 the first time and current_page = 2 into the secound... I'm losted... Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your problem is in the **EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener** class.

Specifically in the onScrolled(...) method

These lines you have to look carefully:

```
visibleThreshold = 5;

if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) 
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) { 
        // End has been reached 

        // Do something 
        current_page++; 

        onLoadMore(current_page); 

        loading = true; 
    }
```

The problem with loading twice, or calling the onLoadMore method twice, is because `totalItemCount is less than visibleItemCount`.

If you have less "vehicles" than visibleItemCount then onLoadMore is called again.

I had the same problem but using this implementation

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

To solve I had to check if totalItemsCount is greater than an arbitrary limit.